# Titanium Payload null

Tags: titanium, payload

Hi I am new to titanium working on one app which receives the push notification from GCM(for android) everything is fine am getting the notification but the payload is null. Cross checked server side script it's fine. This is the response am getting in callback method

```
 This is the GCM response {"type":"callback","source":{"pushType":"gcm","invocationAPIs":[],"showAppOnTrayClick":true,"singleCallback":false,"__propertiesDefined__":true,"bubbleParent":true,"_events":{"callback":{},"trayClickLaunchedApp":{},"trayClickFocusedApp":{}},"focusAppOnPush":false,"enabled":false,"showTrayNotificationsWhenFocused":false,"apiName":"Ti.Module","showTrayNotification":true,"debug":false},"payload":"","bubbles":false,"cancelBubble":false}
```

am using Titanium 3.5.1GA and tried with ti.cloudpush(3.3.7) same issues
any help pls. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to resister successfully for GCM ?

Comment: Yes. and i am getting the notification from the GCM. BUt payload in null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APS Cloud Push - Payload is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281984/aps-cloud-push-payload-is-null).